# How could I deduplicate git submodules that are checking out the same repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-worktree

I would like to track two different branches of a large git repo as submodules in my own repo. For example, the `nixos-unstable` and `nixos-19.03` branches from https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs-channels .

Is there a way to add the submodules so that git would avoid fetching the repo twice and avoid storing two copies of it locally?

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any really *good* way to do this.

There's a fairly hacky method that works, with one glaring defect:

```
$ git submodule add ssh://[url] p1/repo
Cloning into ... [snippage]
Resolving deltas: 100% (173/173), done.
$ git submodule add --reference p1/repo ssh://[url] p2/repo
Cloning into [path]
$
```

Note the total lack of activity beyond the `cloning into` message.  Both submodules now exist but one has an `objects/info/alternates` file containing the path of the other:

```
$ cat .git/modules/p2/repo/objects/info/alternates
[path]/.git/modules/p1/repo/objects
```

so that `p2/repo` retrieves its underlying objects from the `p1/repo` repository's object database in `.git/modules/p1/repo/objects`.

The glaring defect is that none of this arrangement is retained on future clone operations, and none of it happens automatically, ever.  It must be manually constructed each time.